# Does not Redirect to path specified in React JS

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

```
        AuthService.createDesigns(data).then(res => {
            if (res.data.status === "success") {
                const designId = res.data.data.id
                return <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: `${match.url}/${designId}`,
                    props: hoodieData
                }} />
            }
            return true
        })
```

It goes inside the if statement, But does not redirect to path specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Worked

```
        AuthService.createDesigns(data).then(res => {
            if (res.data.status === "success") {
                const designId = res.data.data.id
                history.push({
                    pathname: `${match.url}/${designId}`,
                    state: hoodieData
                })
            }
            return true
        })
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to use `state` instead of `props`?

```
state: hoodieData
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<Redirect>` component can only work if you return it while rendering. You don't show the context of where this code is, but since it's asynchronous it can't possible be rendering anything.

You have two options:

1) Set state, causing a rerender, then render a `<Redirect>`

```
const Example = () => {
  const [redirectTo, setRedirectTo] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    AuthService.createDesigns(data).then(res => {
      if (res.data.status === "success") {
        const designId = res.data.data.id
        setRedirectTo({
          pathname: `${match.url}/${designId}`,
          state: hoodieData
        })
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (redirectTo) {
    return <Redirect to={redirectTo} />
  }

  // else, render the component as normal
}
```

2) Or the one i'd do: use history.replace instead of the `<Redirect>` component

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
  AuthService.createDesigns(data).then(res => {
    if (res.data.status === "success") {
      const designId = res.data.data.id
      history.replace(`${match.url}/${designId}`, hoodieData);
    }
  });
}, []);

// render the component as normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to return a React JSX from an api call? This is not how you are supposed to redirect. Use your history (useHistory hook if you are on latest version of react router);

```
 AuthService.createDesigns(data).then(res => {
        if (res.data.status === "success") {
            const designId = res.data.data.id
            history.replace(`${match.url}/${designId}`, hoodieData);
           // return <Redirect to={{
             //   pathname: `${match.url}/${designId}`,
               // props: hoodieData
           // }} />
        }
        return true
    })
```

Using useHistory hook -

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

AuthService.createDesigns(data).then(res => {
        if (res.data.status === "success") {
            const designId = res.data.data.id
            history.replace(`${match.url}/${designId}`, hoodieData); //or history.push
           // return <Redirect to={{
             //   pathname: `${match.url}/${designId}`,
               // props: hoodieData
           // }} />
        }
        return true
    })
```